# Android Memory Game how to switch between random button that gets highlighted and then user input

Tags: java, android, button, mobile, random

Currently, I am making an android app that is going to be a very simple memory game where 1 random button is going to be highlighted, then the user must click the button that was highlighted after the button goes back to normal. If the user gets the button correct the original button that was highlighted the first time will light up, then another random button will light up after just like the first time and they have to click them in order. For further clarification if your unsure its kind of like Simon (The game) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simon_(game) but for Android.

I currently have this code that gets a random button and displays it but i'm lost on how to do the user input for the game and compare it to what buttons were clicked in the specific order then restarting until they get something wrong. 
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
package com.MakeItMobile.fixmymemory;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import android.R.drawable;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.os.Bundle;  
import android.os.CountDownTimer;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainScreen extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

Button buttonRed, buttonYellow, buttonOrange, buttonBlack, buttonGreen,
        buttonPurple, buttonPink, buttonLime, buttonDarkBlue;

Random randNumber;
int whichButtonToRepeat[] = {};
int userInput[] = {};
int counter = 0;
int compareCounter = 0;
int n = 0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.mainscreen);

    buttonRed = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonRed);
    buttonYellow = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonYellow);
    buttonOrange = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonOrange);
    buttonBlack = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonBlack);
    buttonGreen = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonGreen);
    buttonPurple = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonPurple);
    buttonPink = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonPink);
    buttonLime = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonLime);
    buttonDarkBlue = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonDarkBlue);

    buttonRed.setOnClickListener(this);
    buttonYellow.setOnClickListener(this);
    buttonOrange.setOnClickListener(this);
    buttonBlack.setOnClickListener(this);
    buttonGreen.setOnClickListener(this);
    buttonPurple.setOnClickListener(this);
    buttonPink.setOnClickListener(this);
    buttonLime.setOnClickListener(this);
    buttonDarkBlue.setOnClickListener(this);

    DialogInterface.OnClickListener dialogClickListener = new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            switch (which) {
            case (DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE):
                whenStarted();
                break;

            case (DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE):

                break;
            }
        }
    };
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setMessage("Would you like to begin?")
            .setPositiveButton("Yes", dialogClickListener)
            .setNegativeButton("No", dialogClickListener).show();

}

public void whenStarted() {
    boolean yourTurn = false;
    boolean aiTurn = true;

    if (aiTurn) {
        randomNumber();
        n = randomNumber();
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            System.out.println(n);
            Log.i(null, " " + n);
        }
        if (n == 1) {
            delay(R.drawable.buttonblueclicked, R.drawable.buttonblue);
        } else if (n == 2) {
            delay(R.drawable.buttonblueclicked, R.drawable.buttonblue);
        } else if (n == 3) {
            delay(R.drawable.buttonblueclicked, R.drawable.buttonblue);
        } else if (n == 4) {
            delay(R.drawable.buttonblueclicked, R.drawable.buttonblue);
        } else if (n == 5) {
            delay(R.drawable.buttonblueclicked, R.drawable.buttonblue);
        } else if (n == 6) {
            delay(R.drawable.buttonblueclicked, R.drawable.buttonblue);
        } else if (n == 7) {
            delay(R.drawable.buttonblueclicked, R.drawable.buttonblue);
        } else if (n == 8) {
            delay(R.drawable.buttonblueclicked, R.drawable.buttonblue);
        } else if (n == 9) {
            delay(R.drawable.buttonblueclicked, R.drawable.buttonblue);
        }

        System.out.println(n);

        // whichButtonToRepeat[counter] += n;
        Log.i(null, "The number is : " + n);
        // buttonGreen.setText(whichButtonToRepeat[0]);
        counter++;
        yourTurn = true;
    } else if (yourTurn) {

    }

}

// creating a blinking color button for each specific random number
public void delay(final int newStartID, final int endID) {
    final int time = 1000;
    new CountDownTimer(time, 1000) {

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (n == 1) {
                buttonRed.setBackgroundResource(endID);
            } else if (n == 2) {
                buttonYellow.setBackgroundResource(endID);
            } else if (n == 3) {
                buttonOrange.setBackgroundResource(endID);
            } else if (n == 4) {
                buttonBlack.setBackgroundResource(endID);
            } else if (n == 5) {
                buttonGreen.setBackgroundResource(endID);
            } else if (n == 6) {
                buttonPurple.setBackgroundResource(endID);
            } else if (n == 7) {
                buttonPink.setBackgroundResource(endID);
            } else if (n == 8) {
                buttonLime.setBackgroundResource(endID);
            } else if (n == 9) {
                buttonDarkBlue.setBackgroundResource(endID);
            }

            new CountDownTimer(time, 1000) {

                @Override
                public void onFinish() {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    if (n == 1) {
                        buttonRed.setBackgroundResource(newStartID);
                    } else if (n == 2) {
                        buttonYellow.setBackgroundResource(newStartID);
                    } else if (n == 3) {
                        buttonOrange.setBackgroundResource(newStartID);
                    } else if (n == 4) {
                        buttonBlack.setBackgroundResource(newStartID);
                    } else if (n == 5) {
                        buttonGreen.setBackgroundResource(newStartID);
                    } else if (n == 6) {
                        buttonPurple.setBackgroundResource(newStartID);
                    } else if (n == 7) {
                        buttonPink.setBackgroundResource(newStartID);
                    } else if (n == 8) {
                        buttonLime.setBackgroundResource(newStartID);
                    } else if (n == 9) {
                        buttonDarkBlue.setBackgroundResource(newStartID);
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onTick(long arg0) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }

            }.start();

        }

        @Override
        public void onTick(long arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

    }.start();

}

public int randomNumber() {
    randNumber = new Random();
    int n = randNumber.nextInt(9) + 1;
    return n;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    switch (v.getId()) {
    case (R.id.buttonRed):
        Log.i(null, "testing");
        System.out.println("testing");
        break;
    case (R.id.buttonYellow):

        break;
    case (R.id.buttonOrange):

        break;
    case (R.id.buttonBlack):

        break;
    case (R.id.buttonGreen):

        break;
    case (R.id.buttonPurple):

        break;
    case (R.id.buttonPink):

        break;
    case (R.id.buttonLime):

        break;
    case (R.id.buttonDarkBlue):

        break;
    }
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could, when setting which buttons you want to light up and in what order, do something like:

```
store the order of random numbers in an array.
```

each time you assign that random number to a button

```
buttonRed.setTag(randomNumber());  // button, not just this one
```

and then, when your user clicks a button, inside your click listener,

```
@Override 
public void onClick(View v) {
     Object tag = v.getTag();

     if (tag == storedRandomNumber) {   // proper compare syntax needed here
         found = true;
     }
}
```